# How to iterate through JSON nested objects with ngFor

Tags: javascript, json, angular

I have a GET method that returns the following JSON on route `localhost:3000/documents`

```
[{
"id": "5b48bffc644fca001419769c",
"names": [{
        "name": "bob"
    },
    {
        "name": "stan"
    }
],
"cities": [{
        "city": "London"
    },
    {
        "city": "Madrid"
    }
]
}]
```

I want to concatenate all the names and cities and display them inside HTML tags with Angular.

```
<p> id </p>
<p> concatenated names here </>
<p> concatenated cities here </>
```

Is it possible to access documents and concatenate the array values using ngFor?

I have the following component:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {DocumentService} from '../services/document.service';
import {Document} from './document.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-document',
  templateUrl: './document.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./document.component.css']
})
export class DocumentComponent implements OnInit {
  documents: Document[];

  constructor(private documentService: DocumentService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getDocuments();
  }

  getDocuments(): void {
    this.documentService.getDocuments()
      .subscribe(documents => this.documents = documents);
  }
}
```

And the following service:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';

import {Document} from '../document/document.model';

@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class DocumentService {

  private urlDocuments = 'localhost:3000/documents';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    }

  getDocuments() {
      return this.http.get<Document[]>(this.urlDocuments);
  }
}
```

My document model is:

```
export class Document {
  public _id: string;
  public names: [{ name: string }];
  public cities: [{ city: string }];

  constructor(_id: string, names: [{ name: string }], 
      cities: [{ city: string }]]) {
  this._id = _id;
  this.cities=cities;
  this.names= name;    
  }
}
```

Comment: Are objects inside `names` and `cities`, let's say `{
        "name": "bob"
    }` and `{
        "city": "Madrid"
    }` intended to be a `Document` ?

Comment: I mean how is the JSON related to the code below it? If possible edit the post and clarify that.

Comment: Document model is:   id: String, names:[name: string], cities:[city:string]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the solution, but you need to modify your object.

You have to override toString method for cities and names in your model:

```
test= [{
    "id": "5b48bffc644fca001419769c",
    "names": [{
      "name": "bob",
      toString: function(){return this.name;}
    },
      {
        "name": "stan",
        toString: function(){return this.name;}
      }
    ],
    "cities": [{
      "city": "London",
      toString: function(){return this.city;}

    },
      {
        "city": "Madrid",
        toString: function(){return this.city;}

      }
    ]
  }];
```

HTML section will be look like:

```
<div *ngFor="let t of test">
  <p> {{t.id}}</p>
  <p> {{t.names.join(",")}}</p>
  <p> {{t.cities.join(",")}} </p>
</div>
```

Output:

```
5b48bffc644fca001419769c

bob,stan

London,Madrid
```

Comment: I don´t want to touch the API, and I am a noobie with Angular. Is it possible to do on the Angular side?

Comment: Yes, As i wrote before, you add it with 2 ways. After response recieved or add to model. You could iterate and add this method for all elements

Comment: @RicardoMartin I'm just curious... how did you finally modified the API response in order to add the `toString` function?

Comment: @lealceldeiro convert to model where has toString method

Answer (score 2):

Assume your `documents` data is getting no problem from server, then try this `HTML` code below:

```
 <div *ngFor="let d of documents">
  <p>Id: {{d.id}}</p>
  <p>Names: <span *ngFor="let dd of d.names">{{dd.name}},</span></p>
  <p>Cities: <span *ngFor="let dd of d.cities">{{dd.city}},</span></p>
</div>
```

Comment: This solution will be add comma to the last element. Output look likes Names: bob,stan,

Cities: London,Madrid,

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use an [`*ngFor`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf) in order to iterate over the *documents* and then two [`*ngFor`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf)s for iterating over the `names` and the `cities` like this ([**StackBlitz Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rfotxd?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)):

**ts**:

```
  documents = [{
    "id": "5b48bffc644fca001419769c",
    "names": [{"name": "bob"},{"name": "stan"}],
    "cities": [{"city": "London"},{"city": "Madrid"}]
  },{
    "id": "5b48bffc644fca001419769cde",
    "names": [{"name": "Jon"},{"name": "Doe"}],
    "cities": [{"city": "Barcelona"},{"city": "Saragoza"}]
  }
  ];
```

**html**:

```
<div *ngFor="let doc of documents; let last = last"> <!-- iterate over all documents, let last = last is optional -->
    <p>Id: {{doc.id}}</p>
     <!-- iterate over all names (n) for every document (doc) -->
    <p>Names: <span *ngFor="let n of doc.names; last as lastName">{{n.name}}{{lastName ? '': ','}} </span></p>
     <!-- iterate over all cities (c) for every document (doc) -->
    <p>Cities: <span *ngFor="let c of doc.cities; last as lastCity">{{c.city}}{{lastCity ? '': ','}} </span></p>
     <!-- optional , this will add a separator between documents-->
    <hr *ngIf="!last"/>
</div>
```

**Output**:

[image]